# I'm having a few encoding issues with IE

Tags: html, encoding, character-encoding

In Internet Explorer, I keep coming across these strange diamond symbols whenever a certain character is on the screen. These characters *are copied* from Wordpress and are typically a long dash or an apostrophe.

Here is what these diamond characters look like: http://imgur.com/teheGy4

Whenever I change IE's encoding setting to 'Western European' it fixes the problem. See here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/WYPJF.jpg

So I changed my meta to reflect the 'Western European' setting

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
```

Still no luck in IE, however it did fix the problem in Firefox. Any suggestions on what else can be done to fix this?

Comment: These characters should be getting converted to HTML entities to make them truly cross browser compatible. Where is Wordpress getting this content from? Is it in the post body? The 'the_content' filter should be running htmlentities() on the characters. What Wordpress version and theme are you using? Do you know if the post content is being displayed raw from the DB?

Comment: You are using the — character. Which is known as the em dash `&#151;`.
I found that text from two different sources: http://www.swinglecollins.com/construction-bonds/ and http://www.suretybonds.com/contract-bonds.html

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to get the [corresponding ascii code](http://www.ascii-code.com/) and use that in place of your special characters.

Comment: That will have to work, I was hoping for a quick fix through the meta tag, but that doesn't look like its going to happen.